# Flutter and FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) onMessage, onResume and onLaunch not firing when notification clicked (package: firebase_messaging 7.0.0)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Just an FYI as I found that this problem was caused by me invoking the FCM widget before invoking a FutureBuilder to connect to Firebase Cloud Firestore.

I moved the FCM invocation further down the widget tree, and then onMessage, onResume and onLaunch callbacks fired as expected.

The cloud messaging firebase_messaging 7.0.0 docs recommend:

> "configure should be called early in the lifecycle of your application so that it can be ready to receive messages as early as possible. See the example app for a demonstration."

but obviously not too early!

Answer (score -1):

Answered as per above, I'll link to this on the firebase_messaging GitHub so they're aware.